# Best practice to secure an Electron application from Linux traget

Tags: electron, electron-builder, electron-packager, electron-forge

I have an Electron application packaged into an asar file. However, it's mentioned almost everywhere that there's no security at all for that format. Everyone can unpack it with

```
npx asar extract app.asar destfolder
```

and access the source code + resource files (certificates, images, audio, everything).

Which means technically a person can tamper with the code and resources files as much as they want and create fake builds with unwanted code.

**I want to protect my electron app from tampering by Linux users.** Is there any way to do so?

Comment: *"technically a person can tamper with the code and resources files as much as they want and create fake builds with unwanted code."* - technically, even if its a binary executable people could disassamble them with enough will and skill. i mean, thats how people fork out software cracks (and mods to some extend).

Answer (score 1):

You cant. You could only try to minify/uglify/obscure your code with a bundler like webpack or other tools to make it harder to read. But the whole code will be still accessable to the person who uses your electron app.

So dont store secrets like passwords or private api keys/tokens inside electron app.

And make sure that the tool you use for packaging the app (electron-builder or electron-forge) does not package project files you dont want to include into the app.asar. by default those tools simply put your whole project in the app.asar.

to control what files end up in the app.asar, check those links:

- electron-builder

  - https://www.electron.build/configuration/contents
- electron-forge

  - https://www.electronforge.io/templates/webpack-template
  - https://www.electronforge.io/config/plugins/webpack
  - https://electron.github.io/electron-packager/main/interfaces/electronpackager.options.html#ignore (becareful: is overwritten by the electron-forge webpack-plugin